# Preserve order of Insertion in guava SetMultimap

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have a requirement in which i need to have MultiMap where there should be no duplicate values.
So for this I used Guava SetMultimap.
But now I want to preserve the order of insertion. How do I achieve it with SetMultiMap.
Please any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: Are you looking for `LinkedHashMultimap`?  https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html

Comment: I want something which can preserve the order of Insertion and also does not contain any duplicate values

Comment: From the documentation provided in the link above: "Implementation of Multimap that *does not allow duplicate key-value entries* and that *returns collections whose iterators follow the ordering in which the data was added* to the multimap" (emphasis added).   Note that `LinkedHashMultimap` implements the `SetMultimap` interface (also in the documentation link).

Comment: `LinkedHashMultimap` is what you need, @msandiford is right. It's basically `LinkedHashMap<K, LinkedHashSet<V>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that come along later, here is some test code to show the behavior of `LinkedHashMultimap`:

```
  private static void assertTrue(boolean x)
  {
    if (!x)
    {
      throw new AssertionError();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SetMultimap<String, String> sm = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = Arrays.asList(
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("z", "z"),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("a", "a"),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("x", "x"),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("z", "x") // Multiple values per key OK
    );

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entries)
    {
      assertTrue(sm.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    assertTrue(!sm.put("z", "z")); // Duplicate not added

    // Check iterator ordering is same as insertion order
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i1 = sm.entries().iterator();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i2 = entries.iterator();
    while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext())
    {
      assertTrue(i1.next().equals(i2.next()));
    }
    // Check same number of elements in both collections
    assertTrue(!i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext());
  }
```